# Is function evaluation by neural net faster then the analytical expression for the function itself?

Tags: computational-complexity, neural-networks

Assuming that the analytical function is non-linear such as sin(x), I am interested to know if the mathematical evaluation of the function such as sin(x) by the expansion of Taylor series faster or slower then the evaluation of corresponding approximation of sin(x) via neural nets, with same inputs?

The complexity of computation is lower in neural nets due to its parallel nature so can the function be evaluated faster by neural nets? So to generalize it, is it always good to have expensive functions converted to their corresponding neural net counterparts so they can be evaluated faster for any range of inputs?

Comment: Nothing beats table lookup for a big enough table.

Comment: @Somos so you are suggesting that LUT such as NN is faster then analytical function evaluations?

Comment: It depends on the ratio of RAM memory access time versus CPU/ALU cycle time. Almost always RAM is faster.

Comment: @Somos: a full table for double precision arguments would require like a million billion entries.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If you use linear interpolation then the number of entries needed is much much more reasonable.

Comment: @Somos, I quite didnt get why would we use linear interpolation for a lookup table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accuracy of function approximation that you can obtain with neural nets is very poor (a neural net performs a clumsy interpolation). In addition, the evaluation of a single sigmoid function might be as costly as the evaluation of a sine function.

Never do that.

With a math coprocessor, even a simple polynomial approximation would be beaten by the built-in function.

Comment: Allright. Can you please elaborate why simple polynomial approximation would be beatn by builtin function? Shouldnt lookup tables be faster in general? I am not very much concerned with the accuracy of neural nets because we wont be using them where accuracy is desired but just an argument that lets say we might want to have some evaluation of a expensive function but criteria is that we need evaluation faster so you are suggesting that built-in functions or analytical functions can be evaluated faster compared to some network of lookup tables?

Comment: My bad, I meant neural nets.

Comment: alright makes sense. My motivation was to know that for complex behaviour, is finding analytical form better/faster then simply approximating with neural nets because all complex behavior currently is being dealt with NN. So if possible should we pursue to find the analytical form of the function to gain speed.

Comment: I just have one curious question based on your answer which is bugging me. You said NN perfoms clumsy interpolation but how come GAN networks reproduce images that are highly fluid and connected well, it appears that they are doing very good interpolation..right?

Comment: I cant provide quantitative information so thats why I chose the example of GAN which atleast for qualitative prospective looks visually coherent. Also according to [Universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) NN can be brought closed to certain error bounds. This is why I was wondering what did you mean by them being clumsy interpolators. So I wanted to clarify with you.